# How to send files as arguments of docker commands?

Tags: docker

I'm not sure that I'm trying to do it the right way, but I would like to use docker.io as a way to package some programs that need to be run from the host.

However these applications take filenames as arguments and need to have at least read access. Some other applications generate files as output and the user expects to retrieve those files.

What is the docker way of dealing with files as program parameters?

Comment: I would also try using a volume as Mark says. Or even two: One to read from, and one to write to. @MarkO'Connor, that might be an answer actually, more than a comment. +1 for now.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor: Could you please make it a real answer so I can mark this question as answered ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start Docker with a mounted volume and use this to directory to manipulate files.

See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 4):

If you have apps that require args when they're run then you can just inject your parameters as environment variables when you run your docker container

e.g.

```
docker run -e ENV_TO_INJECT=my_value .....
```

Then in your entrypoint (or cmd) make sure you just run a shell script

e.g. (in Dockerfile)

```
CMD["/my/path/to/run.sh"]
```

Then in your run.sh file that gets run at container launch you can just access the environment variables

e.g.

```
./runmything.sh $ENV_TO_INJECT
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: you could use the environment variable perhaps to pass the file path, and then use the -v hostpath:dockerpath flag (volumes mount) to mount a path on the host machine to the docker container. Then the docker container would be able to access the files on the host machine in that directory and the environment variable would just specify which file to use.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to docker, but could you explain the difference between your method and with simply calling "docker run myimage runmything.sh my_value", with monted volumes?

Comment: Just a different way of solving the problem. You're right in passing any arguments after the command in the docker run command will be passed into the script. That would work just as well as using environment variabes.